# Undefined index: sales_shipment in l/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php

Tags: magento2.3

Trying to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` on a Magento 2.3 site and I keep getting this error:

```
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Notice: Undefined index: sales_shipment in /home/mcrosshutadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

I've cleared the cache, reindexed, disabled modules, removed the `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` and still I get this error.

The magento 2 database has prefixes on the tables so there was no `sales_shipment` table so I copied the `prefix_sales_shipment` table to `sales_shipment` and still the error persists.

How can I clear this error? Is a fresh install of Magento the answer?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet @magefms

Comment: did you try it on your local? with the vendor folder (not removed)